# Computer crashes when trying to install ubuntu

Tags: system-installation

I'm currently trying to reinstall ubuntu 16.04 back onto a partition on one of my hard drives, but whenever I select "Try Ubuntu without installing" or "Install Ubuntu" from my usb, it shows a few messages on the screen

[image]

then briefly shows the purple ubuntu loading screen (for a fraction of a second) and then my pc cycles off and then on. Anyone have some ideas as to what could be a potential cause?

Comment: You should provide more information about your system, like RAM, Disk space, Graphics card, etc. Best regards.

Comment: Unplug ALL unnecessary USB devices and try the install again. If that still fails, boot the Ubuntu DVD/USB with nomodeset enabled.